MariaDb docker container data recovery
I am using MariaDb for the first time for new project, and I just encountered a problem with container crashing after image update. I have updated MariaDb image to latest version (11.3.2 ), but I do not know the old version (probably like more than 6 months old).
What I believe caused the problem was ubuntu reboot, which probably did not wait for all containers to gracefully shutdown.
Either way, my question is this:
Is it possible to copy the data from db-data folder that was mapped to /var/lib/mysql (docker-compose example)?
db:
  image: mariadb:latest
  container_name: db
  networks:
    net:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.188.3
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_ADMN_PWD
    - MARIADB_USER=$DB_LMTD_USR
    - MARIADB_PASSWORD=$DB_LMTD_PWD

If I just start new container, and map its volume to db-data folder, it will continue to crash. So, can I just extract the data from it, and copy it to a newly mapped folder?
